# Internet security when working abroad

Tags: security

I work in the UK and would like to work remotely abroad.  I have been told by my employers that this is not possible because they can't guarantee that data can be kept safe when using the servers abroad.  I think they are making up this reason.

I want to work in Poland.  If what they were saying was correct then no companies would be connecting to internet in Poland as they are using the same servers which my employers say can't guarantee to keep data safe.  There are companies that have staff working in UK and in Poland so they don't have any issue regarding keeping data safe.

So when I work in UK how are my employers guaranteed that the servers used can keep data safe?  I thought there is no such thing as a guarantee to keep data safe as there are breaches in internet security in every country.  Isn't it the internet security software we have on our computers which keeps the data as safe as possible?

If this is the case then it would be no different if I worked in Poland as my internet security software would still be keeping my data just as safe.  Can anyone on here help clarify this for me.

Answer (score 2):

They are likely correct, but only because they have not invested (and maybe lack understanding) of best IT practices, and possibly because they don't have a VPN endpoint.

There are 2 thrusts to this problem.

1. Security of data in transit.  This can be solved with a competently set up VPN.  In a post-covid society any decent size company that cant handle this has unnecessary major risk - we all know about lockdowns - and the concerns of working from home are the same as working abroad - possibly except in the few countries like China which have government level firewalls (not applicable to you).
2. Ability to compromise data/computers.  If data is important the system should use full disk encryption and TPM - built into all x86 laptops capable of running  Windows 11 (and more).  The question to your employer would be "if someone broke into the office or a hard drive or SSD fell into the wrong hands"

In short, likely the company is IT illiterate or incompetent or this is an excuse because they don't want you to work for them remotely.

Comment: We don't store any client data on our hard drives as it is all stored on a remote server.  In the office we log onto the network via the network cable plugged into our computer or via wifi.   When i work from home i'm connecting to this server remotely using the VPN.  When i'm working from home is the client data less safe then when i'm in the office?

Comment: If you are already working from home with VPN, then your employer is being disingenuous.   (Done correctly, data from home is only marginally less safe then in the office - and once you are connecting from outside the office over a VPN, from a technical POV it makes no difference where in the EU - or indeed most of the world you are from a security POV)

Comment: My employer says that when i'm abroad because i use a foreign internet service provider, my empoyers can't guarantee the security of our data on a foreign server.  What should i say to them when they tell me this?  I can't see how they are guaranteeing security more by using ISP server in UK?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines "Our IT staff are competent, and data is sent through a VPN and not stored on foreign servers.   I have it on good authority that the risks involved  are no different between connecting from my home as they are from a foreign country - the VPN and other systems in place provide the same level of protection.  Further, the data adequacy laws in the EU recognise the same security requirements to and from the UK."

Comment: So my employers are not being truthful with me.  Thanks for your feedback.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You remote in using something like WebEx, in such a way that the data never actually leaves their building - you just have a 'view' to it. The data is never actually in your possession, only a 'picture' of it. This involves them setting up the WebEx server for each individual using it this way… something that most IT departments would have shrieked in horror at before covid… but then they were *forced* to get themselves organised, during lockdown.
Now, it's simple.

My partner's company set up 20,000 people to work from home this way in early 2020.
This was a different matter when I first worked remotely, in 2001 [that's not a typo] over a VPN structure on dialup. The world has figured out how to do this now, with considerably less investment.
Get your IT department to do their research.

Comment: So we use Cisco AnyConnect sofware to connect to work network remotely.  So from what you are saying, does it not make any difference in terms of internet security whether i am in UK or Poland if i connect using this same system in both countries?  So when i am in Poland, the data on my work network doesn't use the servers in Poland?

Comment: AnyConnect is a VPN. WebEx is a remote working solution. With a VPN, your data is on your computer. This is insecure. With a remote working solution, as your data never actually leaves the company building at any time whatsoever, it is as secure as the company's building. My partner's company is an international bank. For them security is absolutely paramount. VPN alone isn't good enough at that kind of security level.

Comment: We don't actually store any client data on our computers hard drives because it is all stored on network drives on a remote server.  We just use the VPN to connect to network drives remotely.  We use one time passcodes to log onto the VPN.  So if someone stole the laptop they wouldn't be able to access the client data.  So isn't this secure?

Comment: If your company is already happy with this as a 'work from home' method, then their argument that any other 'foreign server' is less safe is invalid. You would not be using any 'server' except theirs, so their requirement is equally fulfilled in Abu Dhabi as it is in Derby, Fulham or Famagusta. [From your description here & in other comments, it appears that your company is already using a structure similar to WebEx, just DIY-style…  without actually using WebEx itself. If they're happy with it at home, they ought to be happy with it anywhere.]

Comment: Ok that's good to know.  Thanks for your valuable feedback.